# Gradle Build with shared Library results in Multiple menu Icon

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-manifest

I'm working on an App and I decide to dived the code in three projects.

One contains Common Code that I want to use in all my apps. One contains common code that I want to use in some similar projects and it depends on the common Code. And the last one is the main app specific to the customer that depends on the second project.

In the root directory I create a `settings.gradle` file like this

```
include ':CommonLib',':RdsManager',':RdsCommonLib'
```

in each sub directory I create a `build.gradle` file that the dependencies. See below for the sample code.

The apk get correctly compiled but whne I install it in the device (Android 3.2) I found Three Icon of my app.

One launch correctly the main app. One crashes and the last launch the test Activity.

If I create the apk with eclipse everything is normal.

How can I solve this problem using gradle. Do I have to remove the `Androidmanifest.xml` files from the library projects?

below the snipets of the gradle configuration

in `CommonLib/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
....
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar', exclude: 'android-support-v4.jar')
         compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'  

}
```

in `RdsCommonLib/build.gradle`

```
evaluationDependsOn(':CommonLib')

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

and finnaly in RdsManager

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':RdsCommonLib')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to remove the Androidmanifest.xml files from the library projects?

You perhaps have to modify or remove some `<activity>` elements somewhere.

Gradle for Android will merge manifests. If a library project has a manifest with an `<activity>` in it, that activity will automatically be added to the manifest of any app that uses the library.

In your case, your libraries have manifests that have `<activity>` elements in them, where apparently you need to either remove their `<intent-filter>` (if you want the activities to be usable from the app, just not with the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` filter), or remove the `<activity>` elements entirely.

There is [documentation for the manifest merging process](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger), though that link may become obsolete after Gradle for Android reaches 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks removing the `<intent filter>` was the solution. The gradle build configuration was correct.

Thanks.